# WRITE AFTER ADVANCING followed by WRITE causes 2 lines to appear in the first line - Why?

Tags: cobol

I got this result from the code below using a COBOL PC Compiler on Windows.

```
REC 1
FFREC 2-AFTER PAGE    


REC 3 AFTER 3REC 4
```

I can understand the FF at the beginning of the first line.
However, the last output line puts *REC 4 at the SAME LINE as record 3*!
My question is, does MICRO FOCUS COBOL or IBM ENTERPRISE COBOL or Fujitsu COBOL produce the same result? If yes, how to work around this to have a result file one can view on Windows?
Thanks.

**EDIT-1:**
I discovered that if I write:

```
     MOVE "REC 4" TO FD-PRINT-REC
     WRITE FD-PRINT-REC AFTER 1
```

Then the text "REC 4" appears on a separate line.
I assume that this is not the ANSI Standard behavior, I hope you could verify what your compiler does.

**EDIT-2:**

Another option proposed at this thread, the "ASSIGN TO LINE ADVANCING" is probably not something that would work on ENTERPRISE COBOL (not sure):
[GNU COBOL Forum-Related Thread](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnucobol/discussion/help/thread/6debbe116a/?limit=25#5a3d/58f1/3770/b02f/1b05)

The code:

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID.    CALLER.
ENVIRONMENT    DIVISION.
CONFIGURATION  SECTION.
INPUT-OUTPUT   SECTION.
FILE-CONTROL.
SELECT PRINT-FILE ASSIGN TO "X.TXT"
       ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.
*> --------------------------------------------------------------
DATA          DIVISION.
FILE          SECTION.
FD  PRINT-FILE.
01  FD-PRINT-REC               PIC X(132).       
*>---------------------------------------------------------------
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
PROCEDURE DIVISION.

     OPEN  OUTPUT PRINT-FILE  

     MOVE "REC 1" TO FD-PRINT-REC
     WRITE FD-PRINT-REC

     MOVE "REC 2-AFTER PAGE" TO FD-PRINT-REC
     WRITE FD-PRINT-REC AFTER PAGE

     MOVE "REC 3 AFTER 3" TO FD-PRINT-REC
     WRITE FD-PRINT-REC AFTER 3

     MOVE "REC 4" TO FD-PRINT-REC
     WRITE FD-PRINT-REC

     CLOSE PRINT-FILE.

     STOP RUN
     .
```

Answer (score 2):

If none of the files has a LINAGE clause, then if any of the programs use the WRITE statement with the ADVANCING phrase, all of the programs in the run unit that have a WRITE statement must use the WRITE statement with the ADVANCING phrase. [IBM WRITE statement](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cobol-zos/4.2?topic=statements-write-statement)

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID.    CALLER.
ENVIRONMENT    DIVISION.
CONFIGURATION  SECTION.
INPUT-OUTPUT   SECTION.
FILE-CONTROL.
SELECT PRINT-FILE ASSIGN TO "X.TXT"
       ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.
*> --------------------------------------------------------------
DATA          DIVISION.
FILE          SECTION.
FD  PRINT-FILE.
01  FD-PRINT-REC               PIC X(132).       
*>---------------------------------------------------------------
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
PROCEDURE DIVISION.

     OPEN  OUTPUT PRINT-FILE  

     MOVE "REC 1" TO FD-PRINT-REC
     WRITE FD-PRINT-REC END-WRITE

     MOVE "REC 2-AFTER PAGE" TO FD-PRINT-REC
     WRITE FD-PRINT-REC AFTER PAGE  END-WRITE

     MOVE "REC 3 AFTER 3" TO FD-PRINT-REC
     WRITE FD-PRINT-REC AFTER 3 END-WRITE

     MOVE "REC 4" TO FD-PRINT-REC
     WRITE FD-PRINT-REC END-WRITE

     MOVE "REC 5" TO FD-PRINT-REC
     WRITE FD-PRINT-REC AFTER 3 END-WRITE

     MOVE "REC 6" TO FD-PRINT-REC
     WRITE FD-PRINT-REC END-WRITE

     MOVE "REC 7" TO FD-PRINT-REC
     WRITE FD-PRINT-REC END-WRITE

     CLOSE PRINT-FILE.

     STOP RUN.
```

Result:

```
$ cat X.TXT 
REC 1

REC 2-AFTER PAGE


REC 3 AFTER 3REC 4



REC 5REC 6
REC 7
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it looks like you are using UNIX. What compiler are you using, if I may ask? Your statement is correct, but coding a WRITE without ADVANCING is supposed to be equivalent to WRITE ... AFTER ADVANCING 1.

Comment: No room left in the previous one...To continue:  The page in the reference below says "When the ADVANCING phrase is omitted, automatic line advancing is provided, as if AFTER ADVANCING 1 LINE had been specified." however this is incomplete description. Maybe that if no AFTER ADVANCING is coded, the compiler assumes BEFORE ADVANCING and writes the record then advance a line....Not sure. URL:https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cobol-zos/4.2?topic=statements-write-statement

Comment: More continuation...This reference is more specific and says that AFTER ADVANCING 1 is implied: https://bs2manuals.ts.fujitsu.com/psCOBOL2000V16en/cobol2000-user-guide-13779/processing-of-cataloged-files-cobol-compiler-user-guide-81/sequential-file-organization-cobol-compiler-user-guide-87/creating-print-files-cobol-compiler-user-guide-93

Comment: Could you please tell me what compiler are you using? Thanks.